How can I read the response body in a FastAPI middleware without making my endpoint wait for its background tasks to finish?
Sure, here is a clearer version of the text in English:
The provided code shows a FastAPI middleware implementation, which performs an operation with the HTTP response details before returning the response to the user.
The problem is that the response is only returned after the background task in my route is finished.
I believe the issue lies with the line that asynchronously iterates over the response's body_iterator, but I would like to understand why this happens and whether it is possible to achieve my goal of doing something with the response body (such as logging).
Here is code that reproduces the error:
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks, Request, Response
import asyncio
import logging

from starlette.background import BackgroundTask

app = FastAPI()

class AsyncIteratorWrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj) -> None:
        self._it = iter(obj)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            value = next(self._it)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        return value

@app.middleware('http')
async def some_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    
    resp_body = [section async for section in response.__dict__["body_iterator"]]
    response.__setattr__("body_iterator", AsyncIteratorWrapper(resp_body))

    # do something with the response, like logging

    return response


async def any_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

@app.get("/")
async def root(
    bg: BackgroundTasks
):
    bg.add_task(any_task)
    return {"message": "OK"}

I expected to get the response details and send the response to the user, and only after that, allow my background tasks to execute. However, when calling any endpoint that includes this middleware, if the endpoint has a long-running background task (e.g., uploading a file, calling an external API), the response is delayed until the background task completes.
Additionally, if the background task raises an error, the error propagates to the endpoint, causing the API to return an error.
Note: I am using background tasks with FastAPI's BackgroundTasks. The FastAPI version is 0.99.0.

Does this answer your question? Related answer may be found here as well.

@Chris Actually, both suggestions asynchronously iterate over the response's body_iterator, which appears to be the cause of the issue I mentioned. In fact, I have already tested these solutions, and both exhibit the same undesired behavior.

I have refined the question with a clearer code example that reproduces the issue. Also, I am going to investigate the bug you mentioned.

Upgrade to 0.106.0+. This behavior was changed in 0.106.0

I upgraded to latest FastAPI version and the issue was solved. Thank you guys for the help
